# Show that $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equation $y = x^2$ if $(x, y)$ is equidistant from $y = -1/4$ and $(0, 1/4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried a couple of ways but I'm probably missing something obvious.

"The point $(x, y)$ is equidistant from the point $(0, 1/4)$ and the
the line $y = -1/4$. Show that $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equation $y = x^2$."

Well, if the $x$ coordinate of $(x, y)$ is $0$, then $(x, y)$ is also the midpoint of the two distances so the $y$ would also be $0$. That case would satisfy $y = x^2$, but what about the rest? I tried finding the distance between $(x, y)$ and $(0, 1/4)$ and the line, but I didn't really get anywhere with that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The square of the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(0,1/4)$ is $x^2+(y-1/4)^2$.

The distance from $(x,y)$ to $y=-1/4$ is $|y+1/4|$. So the square of this distance is $(y+1/4)^2$.

Comment: Just looked over my work and I think I forgot to square the distance $(y + 1/4)$

Comment: So now a bit of "algebra" will do it.

Comment: Thank you, that was a quick fix. Good to know I was on the right track. I thought it was more complicated I wouldn't have asked this question otherwise.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that this is one of the old geometric definitions of a parabola (or a fact about the parabola if you define it as a conic section). It is the locus of points equidistant from a given point and a given line.

Comment: It all makes sense, the next chapter happens to be about conics. I also think you answered my question yesterday when I asked about an alternate way to solve something, which turned out to be using conics as well.

Comment: Wasn't conics, was similar triangles.

Comment: One of the answers was concerning conics, not yours exactly sorry. I did look at your answer too and also wrote it down.

Comment: To extend **André Nicolas**'s comment on classic definitions of the parabola, the equation for a parabola with a "vertical" symmetry axis is $ \ 4p \ (y-k) \ = \ (x-h)^2 \ , $ with $ \ (h,k) \ $ being the coordinates of the vertex and $ \ p \ $ being the "focal distance".  For $ \ 1 \cdot y \ = \ x^2 \ , $  the vertex is at the origin and the focal distance is $ \ 4p \ = \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ p = 1 \ , $ indicating that the parabola "opens upward", has its focus at $ \ (0, \frac{1}{4}) \ , $ and its directrix is $ \ y  =  -\frac{1}{4} \ . $